# How to reference abstract method from an implemented class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I have a base class (A), below, that I always want to inherited from

```
class A
{
   abstract protected int foo();

   public int foo2()
   {
      //do some stuff

      foo();      
   }

}
```

This will not work because I can't have an abstract method in non-abstract class. But how can I accomplish the follow goals:

classes that inherit class A will have foo2 already implemented but classes that inherit MUST implement foo? It would also be preferable that foo2 is overridable.

Update: Class A did NOT have to be non-abstract

Comment: why can't A be abstract? Make A abstract and add 'virtual' to foo.

Comment: FYI: a clean code principle: favor composition over inheritance

Comment: You can make the `foo()` a `virtual method` with default implementation or create a new `Interface` with that method and make `class A` implement it. Or just make `class A` an `abstract class`.

Comment: Why is `A` not abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the class `A` abstract. Abstract classes can have some methods implemented.

Make `foo2()` virtual, then classes derived from `A` can override it.

Comment: Is virtual really needed? Needing it makes little as sense as inheritors _must_ implement it. Making it virtual must be the choice of direct concrete inheritors instead.

Comment: @Machinarius `virtual` is for `foo2` - the one already implemented in `A`. That was the 2nd requirement - "It would also be preferable that foo2 is overridable."

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you have a valid reason to not make `A` abstract. The prefered way to change the behaviour of an existing non abstract class is to [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) that behaviour.

```
interface IFoo
{
    int Foo();
}

class A
{
    private IFoo foo;

    public A(IFoo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int Foo2()
    {
        //...
        return foo.Foo();            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will receive errors when you build the project
you can't define abstract method in non-abstract class

Exception

```
Error   1   ' .A.foo()' is abstract but it is contained in non-abstract class
```